# Create non static initializer with javassist

Tags: java, javassist

from what i have seen i can make a a new static initializer in a java class using javassist. But what i need is a non static initializer.

So instead of adding:
static{...} to a class i just want to add {..}

The reason i want to do this is because i want to create a classloader that returns classes that are wrapper by ProxyFactory, because i have to add a handler to certain classes. My idea was to add this code to a non static initializer for every class:
((javassist.util.proxy.Proxy)this).setHandler(new library.proxy.Handler());

So, any ideas how to add a non static initializer? Or solve my problem in a different way?
Thank you very much

Comment: You can try [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). javassist doesnt seem to be a good solution for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

At bytecode level, there's no such thing as a non-static initializer in Java. The initializers that you create in the source code, the {} blocks, are actually merged into one and become a part of all the constructors of the class.

So if you need a non-static block to be injected, you have to patch the constructors of the class. Sort of:

```
Constructor[] cs = ctClass.getConstructors();
for(Constructor c: cs) {
  c.insertBefore("your code goes here");
}
```